# Get users order by meta key with limit

Tags: users

Each user in system has meta key called `points`

I need to get top 10 users (highest points)

How I can do this query ?

Should I use `get_users()` with `$args` OR native query

Comment: You should use `get_users()` with `$args`! And what do you mean by Native query ?

Comment: i mean t $wpdb->get_results()

Comment: @Sumit Could u please post an example of the code how it can be done ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `get_users()` with `meta_key` and order by meta value, descending.

**Example:**

```
$user_args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'points',
    'number' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$top_users = get_users($user_args);
```

> **NOTE:** Support for `meta_value_num` is available only from version 4.2

Comment: An addendum to this answer, answering OP's question on *"using `get_users()` or `$wpdb->get_results()`"*: if possible, don't use raw SQL queries to perform operations that WordPress supports natively. There are several reasons for this: (1) it prevents WordPress from applying filters to the return value, thereby interrupting native functionality; (2) it can yield unexpected results because certain clauses that WordPress includes are not included in your custom SQL; (3) it prevents possible caching and (4) when WordPress changes its internal functionality, you don't want your code to break.